# Django ImageField overwrites existing path when empty

Tags: django

So, that's the problem:
 I currently have a model:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Avatar',upload_to='images/profile_pics',blank=True,null=True)
    doc_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Document type',max_length=1,default='0')
```

And a form:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(label='Avatar',required=False, error_messages = {'invalid':"Images only"}, widget=forms.FileInput)
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
```

So, the problem occurs when the user tries to edit his data. When no image is provided, the current image path in the db overwrites with the empty string. Is there any way to solve that problem?

Comment: You can programm your own save() method into your form.

Comment: So, I have to check if the image is provided, and then decide whether to save it or not?

Comment: exactly, if there is an empty value send by your form, just ignore it, else set the send value...

Comment: why did you overwrite the avatar field in your form ?

Answer (score 0):

```
avatar = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Avatar',upload_to='images/profile_pics',null=True)
```

removing `blank=True` should solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by making image field required.

```py
avatar = forms.ImageField(label='Avatar', required=True, error_messages={'invalid':"Images only"}, widget=forms.FileInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove both `blank and null` equal to `True`

`blank=True`

Allows the field to be empty

`null=True`

Allows the empty data to be saved in database

so you can choose which one will work for you the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import connection

@login_required
```

def card_photo_remove(request, pk):
card = get_object_or_404(Cards, cardid=pk)

```
if card.sponsorimage:
    default_storage.delete(card.sponsorimage.path)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Cards SET SponsorImage=NULL WHERE cardid=%s", [pk])

return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Here u can see exaple how to write manyal SQL code. It worked to me perfectly!